# How can I get the values from the PHP generated forms?

Tags: php, forms

I dont know where or how to use $_POST to get the values of the forms.

[This is the whole code, I uploaded it on GitHub if you want to see the whole thing](https://github.com/JustKaZMa/websiteproject)

This is the file I am trying to get the values out of.

new.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST) and isset($_POST['actiune']))
{
$actiune = isset($_POST['actiune']) ? $_POST['actiune'] : NULL;
switch($actiune){
//CASE 1
case 'addElev': echo '<div class=dbFormText>Adauga elev</div><div 
class="databaseform"><form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="numeElev" placeholder="Nume elev"/>
<input type="text" name="orasElev" placeholder="Localitate"/>
<select name="sexElev">
<option value="Baiat">Baiat</option>
<option value="Fata">Fata</option></select>
<input type="text" name="tlfElev" placeholder="Nr. de telefon"/>
<input type="text" name="birthdayElev" placeholder="Nastere(DD-MM-YYYY)"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form></div>';
break;
}
}
?>
```

This is the page of the first dropdown, which gives me the value of the switch

adminpanel.html

```
<div class="dropdowns">
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="actiune" onchange="this.form.submit()">
<option>Selecteaza actiunea</option>
<option value="addElev">Adauga elev</option>
<option value="addNota">Adauga nota</option>
<option value="addAbsenta">Adauga absenta</option>
<option value="addTeza">Adauga teza</option>
<option value="deleteElev">Sterge elev</option>
<option value="deleteNota">Sterge nota</option>
<option value="deleteAbsenta">Sterge absenta</option>
<option value="deleteTeza">Sterge teza</option>
<option value="modifyElev">Modifica elev</option>
<option value="modifyTeza">Modifica teza</option>
<option value="modifyPurtare">Modifica nota purtare</option>
</select>
<?php include('new.php') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Form POST to PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057752/html-form-post-to-php-page)

Comment: @yak0d3 Why do you feel that what they're asking is related to what you think as being a possible duplicate?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Well the first line says it all : "I dont know where or how to use $_POST to get the values of the forms.". The possible duplicate is about the same thing, basically "sending data from HTML From to PHP"

Comment: You're alreay using `$_POST['actiune']` in your code, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @yak0d3 The reference you linked is more about PHP not being parsed properly.

Comment: @yak0d3 You are wrong. I want everything in the same page, I overcomplicated a project. I got a dropdown which gives me the value for "$actiune". The switch only checks which form to show(This part works) but I can't seem to be able to retrive the values of these forms.
[This is how it works](https://imgur.com/a/toszcab).

Comment: @KaZma what are you trying to do here? Your question is unclear. All you posted was code that doesn't really *do* anything. Where and how are you echoing/getting back the values from? Also, are you running this off a webserver and using an HTTP protocol, or are you accessing it directly into your browser as `file:///`? Your question is unclear for many reasons.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, but still i think this has the same subject, and is more likely to be a duplicate

Comment: See the answer(s) below then.

Comment: @KaZMa first of all, please do not take anything personally, it's just for the community's best.
If you haven't mentioned enough details and i have flagged your question as a duplicate, that is not my fault.
I had two choices: One: Flag as duplicate and help you find an answer. Two: Flag as not constructive.
Again, nothing to be taken personal here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner It is on my Apache 2.4 server. I just don't know how/can't retrive the values of the form in the same page. I edited my other comment and added an image of how  the site looks.

Comment: @yak0d3 I know it is nothing personal. But imo it is not the same thing. That guy wanted it from a html page to transfer to a php page. I want it to retrive me the values in the same page.

Comment: I still think this has been asked in SO even after knowing more details about the issue. Here is another similar to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540558/how-to-post-in-the-same-page-in-simple-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a form that has a method of `post`, e.g.

```
<form method="post">
```

*(note: `action=""` is redundant and can be left out)*

the target page (in this case, itself) will be provided with the `$_POST` array.

You can dump the entire array to look at the values by using:

```
if (!empty($_POST) and isset($_POST['actiune']))
{
var_dump($_POST);
}
```

This array should contain all the values from within the `<form>` tag, provided a `name` has been set (which will be used as the 'key' in the array).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is the switch for, added the fetch of postvars at the top of code. I am sure you can do some php to make sure vars are set. Also actiune is not a postvar that is its not the name of anyof the input fields so dont do $_POST['actiune']. it wont work. Else you have to add a hidden field, I did it here for you.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST) {

    $numeElev = $_POST['numeElev'];
    $orasElev = $_POST['orasElev'];
    $sexElev = $_POST['sexElev'];

    }


    if (!empty($_POST) and isset($_POST['actiune']))
    {
    $actiune = isset($_POST['actiune']) ? $_POST['actiune'] : NULL;
    switch($actiune){
    //CASE 1
    case 'addElev': echo '<div class=dbFormText>Adauga elev</div><div 
    class="databaseform"><form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="numeElev" placeholder="Nume elev"/>
    <input type="text" name="orasElev" placeholder="Localitate"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="actiune" placeholder="1"/>
    <select name="sexElev">
    <option value="Baiat">Baiat</option>
    <option value="Fata">Fata</option></select>
    <input type="text" name="tlfElev" placeholder="Nr. de telefon"/>
    <input type="text" name="birthdayElev" placeholder="Nastere(DD-MM-YYYY)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form></div>';
    break;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: $_POST['actiune'] comes from another form. I would've posted all the code, but it is way too long.